# My [Column(TypeName="varchar(10)")] does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

I set attribute to `benefitID` to `[Column(TypeName="varchar(10)")]` but when I run it `benefit` is `nvarchar(450)`.

```cs
[Key]
[Column(TypeName="varchar(10)")]
[StringLength(20)]
[Required]
private string benefitID;
private string benefitContent;//nội dung quyền lợi
public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

public string BenefitID { get => benefitID; set => benefitID = value; }
public string BenefitContent { get => benefitContent; set => benefitContent = value; }

public Benefit() 
{
    Jobs = new HashSet<Job>();
}
```

I want `benefit` when running to be `varchar(10)`.

Comment: The attribute won't change the type of an existing table column. It won't override any explicit migration scripts either

Comment: Does the table already exist? Or are you creating it using migrations? If so, how do you apply the migrations?

Comment: EF won't use an arbitrary number like 450 for a column size. This was specified either in the application or table creation script.

Comment: As far as I know, EF Attributes must be placed on the public properties, not on the private backing fields for those properties.

Comment: varchar(10) says the size is 10, stringlenght(20) says the size is 20 -- which is it?